# Mutability of Lists

Tags: python, list

When a list is sorted, perhaps in ascending numerical order (for integer only list) or alphabetical order in case of strings (for string only list), can I say that the list is mutated, considering the fact that the index number of the items in the list have been changed?
For example:

```
x = ["Alexa", "Siri", "Cortana"]
x_sorted = sorted (x)
print (x_sorted)
# ["Alexa", "Cortana", "Siri"]
print (x)
# ["Alexa", "Siri", "Cortana"]
```

Comment: You haven't mutated the list though, you've created a copy with items in a different order. If you did `x.sort()`, that would be mutating x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how you do the sort. If your initial list is

```
>>> x = ["Alexa", "Siri", "Cortana"]
```

using `sorted` will create a new list, and will leave the original unmutated

```
>>> sorted(x)
['Alexa', 'Cortana', 'Siri']
>>> x
['Alexa', 'Siri', 'Cortana']
```

However the `sort` method will sort the list in-place, and therefore does mutate the list in doing so

```
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
['Alexa', 'Cortana', 'Siri']
```